# Проблема с приватными свойствами объекта

Tags: javascript

Как обратится к  `jumps`?

```
function Animal(name) {
var speed = 10
return {
    name: name,
    run: function() { 
        alert(jumps)
    }
}
}

function Rabbit(name) {

var me = Animal(name)  
var jumps = 0   
me.jump = function() { jumps++ }
me.getJumps = function() { return jumps }
me.constructor = arguments.callee

return me
}
```

var ogj = Rabbit()

Comment: Rabbit(name).getJumps();

Comment: я имею ввиду к свойству, а не к методу по типу
Rabbit(name).jumps

Comment: Вы уверены, что на JS пишете? И что понимаете то, что пишете?

Comment: Это не моя функция, http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance

Comment: > Не всё, происходящее при наследовании в javascript, статья описывает абсолютно корректно.

сами авторы утверждают о своём невежестве! и даже после этого вы продолжили её читать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой смысл приватного свойства, если к нему так просто получить доступ из вне?

Собственно ответ на твой вопрос прост до безобразия - никак. Так-же добавлю - `jumps`, как-бы, не свойство, а переменная.

PS: Справедливости ради добавлю - в языках с классической реализацией ООП, обычно, доступ к приватным свойствам можно получить использую reflation. Но в вопросе речь не о таком языке, к тому-же, речь даже не о свойстве.

Comment: а зачем тогда использовать приватные переменные ?

Comment: просто facepalm

Comment: что-бы их нельзя было изменить, наподобе констант только в объекте ?

Answer (score 0):

Что это за синтаксическая конструкция, оно как работать должно по задумке?
К переменной `jumps` никак не добраться - она существует локально в рантайме `Rabbit`. Если бы Вы приписали

```
me.jumps = 0; me.jump = function (){return this.jumps++}
```

тогда да, у вас переменная будет свойством возвращаемого объекта и к ней будет доступ.